# boolean.class?

Tags: java

I noticed the other day that I can call boolean.class, but not integer.class (or on other primitives). What makes boolean so special?

Note: I'm talking about boolean.class, not Boolean.class (which would make sense).

Duh: I tried integer.class, not int.class. Don't I feel dumb :\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not `integer.class` but `int.class`. Yes you can. JRE 6 :

```
public class TestTypeDotClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(boolean.class.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(int.class.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(float.class.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(Boolean.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

outputs

```
boolean
int
float
java.lang.Boolean
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do `int.class`. It gives the same as `Integer.TYPE`.

`int.class.isPrimitive()`, `boolean.class.isPrimitive()`, `void.class.isPrimitive()`, etc., will give a value of `true`. `Integer.class.isPrimitive()`, `Boolean.class.isPrimitive()`, etc., will give a value of `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do something like `int.class` as well

```
System.out.println(int.class);
```

The .class keyword was introduced with Java 1.1 to have a consistent way to get the class object for class types and primitive data types.

[class: Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/class.html)

Answer (score 3):

boolean isn't special.  You can call

```
int.class
```

for example.  All of the primitive types have this literal.  From Sun's [Tutorial](http://www.j2ee.me/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Finally, there's also a special kind of literal called a class literal, formed by taking a type name and appending ".class"; for example, String.class. This refers to the object (of type Class) that represents the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dumb continuation, but why is possible to assign boolean.class to Class<Boolean>, although hashCodes are different?

```
final Class<Boolean> c = boolean.class;     
System.out.println("c := "+c);
System.out.println("boolean.class := "+boolean.class);
System.out.println("Boolean.class := "+Boolean.class);
System.out.println("boolean.class == Boolean.class := "+(boolean.class == Boolean.class));
System.out.println("boolean.class.equals(Boolean.class) := "+boolean.class.equals(Boolean.class));
System.out.println("boolean.class.hashCode := "+boolean.class.hashCode());
System.out.println("Boolean.class.hashCode := "+Boolean.class.hashCode());
```

Comment: Because the type of `boolean.class` is `Class<Boolean>`. Primitives can't be used as type arguments, so there is no such thing as the type `Class<boolean>`. And it's best not to submit questions as answers. This should be its own question, or maybe a comment on one of the other answers.