# How to get class of primitive types with Javassist?

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

In my program, I deal with classes and primitive types.
If the program finds a class, it simply does one of the following calls :

- `Class.forName(classname)`
- `cc.toClass()` where `cc` is an instance of `CtClass`

However, if it finds a primitive type, things get worse :

- `Class.forName` is not usable, it cannot be used with primitive types.
- `cc.toClass()` returns `null`

It's possible to call the `TYPE` field from primitive types wrapper class but how can I do it with reflection ?

Here is my code :

```
CtClass cc;//Obtained from caller code
Class<?> classParam;
if (cc.isprimitive()) {
    classParam= ?? // How can I get TYPE field value with reflection ?
} else {
    String nomClasseParam = cc.getName();

    if (nomClasseParam.startsWith("java")) {
        classeParam = Class.forName(nomClasseParam);
    } else {
        classeParam = cc.toClass();
    }
 }
```

**Javassist 3.12.0.GA**

**EDIT:**
I have posted [the solution I chose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389115/363573) in the anwsers below.
Anyway, I ticked [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388422/363573).

Comment: This other question will definitely help: [boolean.class ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019208/boolean-class)

Comment: @Andreas_D Not much since I want to perform the call with java reflection.

Comment: but we *can* use `boolean.class`, `int.class` and so on as `Class` objects when we reflect methods and constructors

Comment: With the sample code in the question how can I achieve it ?

Comment: This question is not really about reflection, it's about javassist. The question is how we can get from an instance of CtClass to an instance of Class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you can cast `cc` to its subclass [CtPrimitiveType](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtPrimitiveType.html).

If you wanted a wrapper, you could then use the method [getWrapperName](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtPrimitiveType.html#getWrapperName%28%29) to get the class name of the appropriate wrapper. You can use [Class.forName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) as usual to turn that name into a `Class` object. However, i don't think you do want a wrapper, so this doesn't help.

Instead, i think you want [getDescriptor](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtPrimitiveType.html#getDescriptor%28%29), followed by a laboriously handcoded switch statement:

```
switch(descriptor) {
    case 'I': classParam = int.class; break;
    // etc
}
```

Something like that really should be in Javassist. But as far as i can see, it isn't.

Comment: Finally, I use `getWrapperName` and I avoid having to code a switch statement.

Comment: Given that there are only eight primitive types, it wouldn't be *that* laborious to write.

Answer (score 3):

Based on responses from Tom and momo, here is the solution I came up with :

```
CtClass cc; //Obtained from caller code
Class<?> classParam;

if (cc.isprimitive()) {
    classParam = Class.forName(((CtPrimitiveType)cc).getWrapperName());
    classParam = (Class<?>)classParam.getDeclaredField("TYPE").get( classParam );
} else {
    String nomClasseParam = cc.getName();

    if (nomClasseParam.startsWith("java")) {
        classeParam = Class.forName(nomClasseParam);
    } else {
        classeParam = cc.toClass();
    }
 }
```

I call `CtPrimitiveType#getWrapperName` method and then I use the TYPE field to get the primitive type class. I also avoid writing a switch statement.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the Class.forName for the Object wrapper of primitive (e.g. Integer for primitive int). Java supports autoboxing, so you could interchange between the Object wrapper and the primitive counterpart.

I am assuming that you are using [CtClass](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html) from JavaAssist.
If `cc` is a primitive, I think it will be a type of `CtPrimitiveType` (need to confirm) in which case you could  cast and call [getWrapperName()](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtPrimitiveType.html#getWrapperName%28%29) to get the wrapper class.

Comment: Not true in the world of reflection. :(

Comment: You're right, Java does support autoboxing but the class I manipulate is dynamically generated by Javassist. The generated class has a method with `int` parameter. The classloader is unable to find this method if I give him `java.lang.Integer` parameter in `Class.forName`.

Comment: @dawce Argh, I didn't know that :( Should play with reflection more. Stephan looks like Tom's answer should work.

Comment: cc *is* type of `CtPrimitiveType`. I'll check `getWrapperName`